# Не работает разрешение имен DNS

Tags: linux, dns, archlinux

Столкнулся с тем, что не работает DNS-резолвинг на моем линуксе, хотя вроде бы все правильно настроено. В качестве DNS-сервера использую свой роутер. Сам роутер прекрасно резолвит DNS, так что проблема не в роутере. С интернет-соединением все в порядке, google пингуется по IP-адресу, но не по имени хоста.

```
$ uname -a
Linux archlinux 4.8.11-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Nov 27 09:26:14 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Имя или служба не известны

$ ping -c 2 216.58.201.142
PING 216.58.201.142 (216.58.201.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 216.58.201.142: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=195 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.201.142: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=110 ms

--- 216.58.201.142 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 110.924/153.054/195.185/42.132 ms


$ host google.com
google.com has address 216.58.201.142
google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4003:804::200e
google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.

$ dig google.com
; <<>> DiG 9.11.0-P1 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 58292
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A
;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     79  IN  A   216.58.201.142
;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Вс дек 04 21:24:39 +05 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55

$ resolveip google.com
resolveip: Unable to find hostid for 'google.com': host not found

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
search 192.168.1.1
nameserver 192.168.1.1

$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
passwd: files
group: files
shadow: files
publickey: files
hosts: files mdns_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] myhostname
networks: files
protocols: files
services: files
ethers: files
rpc: files
netgroup: files
```

Comment: Хм. что то странное. dig то работает ... Попробуйте исключить avahi поменяв в nsswitch строку hosts на `hosts:       files dns`

Comment: Вот спасибо! Все заработало!

Answer (score 2):

Проблема [решена](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599528/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd-dns/599542#comment811271_599528) благодаря [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike), за что ему спасибо:

В `/etc/nsswitch.conf` можно было указать другие источники резолвинга имён машин:

```
hosts: files dns
```